# Query on DNS & connect to existing vm

Tags: rest, azure

In my current code base, when i create a VM, DNS name is being dynamically set as same as the instance name. For example, consider if my VM name is "anandInstance", DNS name of the name is being generated as "anandInstance.cloudapp.net". Is there a way to change the DNS name like "dns1.cloudapp.net" during the creation thru REST API??

```
"Connect to existing VM" , is it possible to achieve this option through REST call? In case "connect to existing.." option , we are getting a list of vms/services to choose and VM is getting created successfully. How to achieve the same using API.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my current code base, when i create a VM, DNS name is being
>   dynamically set as same as the instance name. For example, consider if
>   my VM name is "anandInstance", DNS name of the name is being generated
>   as "anandInstance.cloudapp.net". Is there a way to change the DNS name
>   like "dns1.cloudapp.net" during the creation thru REST API??

I don't think it is possible. Imagine what a nightmare in the portal would become if you were able to do so? How would you link a Cloud Service (whatever.cloudapp.net) to an actual deployment (MyDemoVm123). However you can use your own domain and have CNAME records pointing to your "want-to-change-for-some-reason.cloudapp.net" (frankly I surely think that soon we will use even longer names)

> "Connect to existing VM" , is it possible to achieve this option
>   through REST call?

Connection to a VM is essentially opening a RDP session. If it a windows VM, you can try using the [Download RDP file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157183.aspx) API call. Once you get the file, just start it with "process.start". If it is linux VM, just start SSH client on port 22 (or one you have defined) from the Cloud Service DNS name you have.

**UPDATE**

> From the azure portal,for stand alone machineoption, we are able to give the dns name with deafult cloudoneapp.net. How to do the same
>   through the rest api call.any specfic paramter is there to specify the
>   same?

When you are using the REST API, you first [create a Cloud Service (still named hosted service in the REST API)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg441304.aspx) where your machine will be hosted. Here you give the name for that hosted service (the `dns name with deafult cloudoneapp.net`). Then you call the [Create Virtual Machine Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj157194) API action.

> In case "connect to existing.." option , we are getting a list of vms/services to choose and VM is getting created successfully. How to
>   achieve the same using API.

When you want to get list of all VMs, just [get a list of all Hosted Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460781.aspx), then get properties of each and make a guess whether it is a VM or a Cloud Service (maybe by [querying for Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460806.aspx) of each service). I don't see a direct access to the list of Virtual Machines. But as this feature being **PREVIEW**, things might change in the future.

Hope my answer is clear?

Comment: Hi Astay,
  1. From the azure portal,for stand alone machineoption, we are able to give the dns name with deafult cloudoneapp.net. How to do the same through the rest api call.any specfic paramter is there to specify the same?
  2. In case "connect to existing.." option , we are getting a list of vms/services to choose and VM is getting created successfully. How to achieve the same using API. Hope my question is clear?